# Session laravel key para groupby

Tags: laravel

Tengo este foreach de una session laravel, necesito eliminar las sessiones pero necesito la key de la session antes del groupby para poder eliminarlo porq en el grouped me arroja la id del vendedor y no de la session.

```
$carrito=Session::get('cart');
          $grouped = Session::get('cart')->groupBy('vendedor');

    foreach($carrito as $clave => $carro){
   echo $clave ; //necesito poner estas clavesen el <a> para poder eliminar la session de ese item porque al aplicar groupby no me da la key de la session. 
}
  @foreach($grouped as $id => $value)
@foreach($value as $key => $cartItem)
 <a href="#" onclick="removeFromCartView(event, {{ $clave}})" class="text-right pl-4"><i class="la la-trash"></i></a>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos un dump de $carrito para tener una idea de su estructura?

Comment: Gracias ya lo solucione poniendo ->groupBy('vendedor', $preserveKeys = true)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $grouped = Session::get('cart')->groupBy('vendedor', $preserveKeys = true)
```

Esta es la solucion